# Given an dictionary of words and and an array letters, find the maximum number of dictionary words which can be created using those letters

Tags: algorithm

Each letter can be used only once.  There may be more than one instance of the same letter in the array.

We can assume that each word in the dict can be spelled using the letters.  The goal is to return the maximum number of words.

Example 1:

```
arr = ['a', 'b', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'z']
dict = ['ab', 'azz', 'bzz']
// returns 2 ( for [ 'azz', 'bzz' ])
```

Example 2:

```
arr = ['g', 't', 'o', 'g', 'w', 'r', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b']
dict = ['we', 'bag', 'got', 'word']
// returns 3 ( for ['we', 'bag', 'got'] )
```

**EDIT** for clarity to adhere to SO guidelines:

Looking for a solution.  I was given this problem during an interview. My solution is below, but it was rejected as too slow.

```
1.) For each word in dict, w
  - Remove w's letters from the arr.
  - With the remaining letters, count how many other words could be spelled.  
    Put that # as w's "score"
2.) With every word "scored", select the word with the highest score,  
    remove that word and its letters from the input arrays.
3.) Repeat this process until no more words can be spelled from the remaining 
    set of letters.
```

Comment: do you want solution in python?

Comment: So what is your question? Are you asking us to do your homework for you? We're happy to help, but you need to show some effort. Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: also description is unclear and with errors - you can clearly create more words than provided in example

Comment: @stetoc the dict is given as an input parameter.  We're looking to create only the words defined in dict.  In example 2, "word" is not in the result because it would consume letters 'o' and 'w', and we could create more words by creating 'we' and 'got' instead.

Comment: Can a word be used more than once?

Comment: @squeamishossifrage would that technique find `azz` in the first example?

Comment: The problem can be reduced by removing letters that don't force a choice. The first example reduces to `arr = ['a','b']` with `dict=['ab','a','b']`. Example 2 reduces to `arr = ['o','w']` with `dict=['w','o','wo']`. Note that `'bag'` doesn't contain any letters that force a choice, so it's guaranteed to be part of the output.

Comment: @Mark_M Ah, looks like I didn't read the question properly. Never mind...

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly generic packing problem with up to 26 resources. If I were trying to solve this problem in practice, I would formulate it as an integer program and apply an integer program solver. Here's an example formulation for the given instance:

```
maximize x_ab + x_azz + x_bzz
subject to
constraint a: x_ab + x_azz <= 1
constraint b: x_ab + x_bzz <= 1
constraint z: 2 x_azz + 2 x_bzz <= 4
x_ab, x_azz, x_bzz in {0, 1} (or integer >= 0 depending on the exact variant)
```

The solver will solve the linear relaxation of this program and in the process put a price on each letter indicating how useful it is to make words, which guides the solver quickly to a provably optimal solution on surprisingly large instances (though this is an NP-hard problem for arbitrary-size alphabets, so don't expect much on artificial instances such as those resulting from NP-hardness reductions).

I don't know what your interviewer was looking for -- maybe a dynamic program whose states are multisets of unused letters.

Comment: If they reject your solution as too slow, without any prior specification of necessary speed then point out their flaw!

Answer (score 0):

Expression for One possible Dynamic Programming solution can be following:

```
WordCount(dict,i,listOfRemainingLetterCounts) = 
   max(WordCount(dict,i-1,listOfRemainingLetterCounts),
       WordCount(dict,i-1,listOfRemainingLetterCountsAfterReducingCountOfWordDict[i]))
```

I see it as a multidimensional problem. Was the interviewer impressed by your answer?

Comment: They were not impressed, I did not continue onto the next step of the interview process.  I assume it was due to my given answer.

Answer (score 0):

Turn the list of letters into a set of letter-occurence pairs. Where the occurrence is incremented on each occurrence of the same letter in the list e.g. `aba` becomes set of `a-1 b-1 a-2`

Translate each word in the dictionary, independently, in a similar manner; so The word `coo` becomes a set: `c-1 o-2`.

A word is accepted if the set of its letter-occurences is a subset of the set generated from the original list of letters.

For fixed alphabet, and maximum letter frequencies, this could be implemented quite quickly using bitsets, but, again, how fast is fast enough?